# How get data in method from others tables?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

[image]

This is my simple db schema. Now in my group table i have 'group_A' and 'group_B'. In questions table i have 10 questions 5 for group_A and 5 for group_B. Users table is one user with ID = 1. What i try to do is get data like this:

```
SELECT answer
FROM answers
JOIN questions q ON (q.id = answer.question_id)
JOIN group g ON (g.id = q.group_id)
WHERE user_id = 1 AND g = 'group_A'
```

I have model in users class and i would like create method to get answers depend from group:

```
public function getAnswers($group) {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answers', 'question_id', 'id');
    }
```

How can i get this in that method ? Should i create method group in questions class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how to define such relation in model which takes input parameter but you could define a scope in your model to get the answers filtered by group like

```
class Answer extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }

    public function scopeGroup($query, $name)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('question.group', function($q) use($name){
                    $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        });
    }
}
```

I assume in answers model you have defined relationship for question and similarly in question model you have defined relationship for group model.

In query builder you could write it as

```
$answers = Answer::group('group_A')
                 ->whereHas('user', function($q) use($userid){
                    $q->where('id', '=', $userid);
                 })->get();
```

Or you could apply filter on eager loaded relations as

```
$users = User::with(['answers' => function($query)
{
    $query->whereHas('question.group', function($q){
        $q->where('name', '=', 'group_A');
    });

}])->get();
```

If you already have user object you can get answers for specific group as

```
$answers = $user->answers()
                ->whereHas('question.group', function($q){
                    $q->where('name', '=', 'group_A');
            })->get();
```